# Regex to find functions with 4 parameters but not 3

Tags: regex

I have following text

```
 test(strpos (in_sop_instance_euid, '.', -1, 1) -1)
           aws_oracle_ext.TO_CHAR(plvstr.substr(in_sop_instance_euid,
                TRUNC((strpos (in_sop_instance_euid, 'OK', -1, 1) + 1)::NUMERIC)::INTEGER)::NUMERIC + 1));
        END IF;
          
          (not_capture (in_sop_instance_euid, 'TEST', -1, 1) -1)
           aws_oracle_ext.TO_CHAR(plvstr.substr(in_sop_instance_euid,
                TRUNC((strpos (in_sop_instance_euid, 'OK', 1) + 1)::NUMERIC)::INTEGER)::NUMERIC + 1));
                TRUNC((strpos (in_sop_instance_euid, 'NG') + 1)::NUMERIC)::INTEGER)::NUMERIC + 1));
        END IF;
```

I want to capture function `strpos` with following parameters by regex : `strpos[^(]+\(([^()]+)\)`
But I only want capture which has 4 parameters

https://regexr.com/576e7

Are there anyway to do it?

Comment: This may be difficult/impossible to do with regex alone, as it appears the function calls can be _nested_.  Consider writing a parser instead.

Comment: What if there is another function that has 4 parameters? and one of the parameters is the  a call to a function?

Answer (score 2):

This will work if there are no nested calls:

```
strpos\s*\([^,)]+(,[^,)]+){3}\)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/fQ7ot9HTm0jQyi).